# In a tabpage GUI Extension, what does the ext:pagetype node do?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a GUI Extension adding a Tab (ext:tabpage) to View.

What does the ext:pagetype node do?  I have been using Namespace:Name like the following.  Are there other options for the value?

```
<ext:pagetype>RC.TabExtension</ext:pagetype>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It allows you to have a specific JavaScript implementation for that tab.

If you specify the full name of a JavaScript class and it implements the `Tridion.Controls.DeckPage` interface, it will use that implementation for the tab.

If it's not a class or it doesn't implement the interface, it will just use the default implementation.

(Tabs inherit from Decks, in case you are wondering)

Comment: Great answer.  Example of a DeckPage can be found in the PowerTools 2011 project at http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/PowerTools/Client/ItemXml/ItemXmlTab.ascx.js?r=563

Comment: The only thing is that it's not a "full name of a JavaScript class" but registered unique Page type, associated with JavaScript class.

When you creating new DeckPage, you had to register it. This could be done with single line (took from example above):

Tridion.Controls.Deck.registerPageType(ItemXmlTab.ItemXmlTab, "ItemXmlTab");

So "ItemXmlTab" should be used in <ext:pagetype> node.